# How to apply a matrix identity to a matrix expression in Mathematica or SymPy?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, sympy, symbolic-math

For example, I have a matrix expression $(A+BCD)^{-1}$ and hope to apply Sherman-Morrison-Woodbury formula to it. It's quite tedious to expand the expression by hand. Is there a convenient way to do it in Mathematica or SymPy or any other symbolic math software?

Comment: What exactly is the formula you would like to apply? The Wikipedia article lists that formula in terms of vectors `u` and `v`, not `BCD`.

Comment: And if you could give an example of what your matrix looks like that would help too. Is it symbolic or numeric? How large is it?

Comment: @asmeurer here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity

Comment: I'm still unclear what exactly you want SymPy to do.  If you know what A, B, C, and D are just plug them into the rhs of the formula.